# How do I know which header is being included?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing a set of unit tests, and creating stubs for classes that the unit test needs to compile and link. I would like to know whether the real header is being included, or the fake(stub) header is being included for these headers that I'm tying to stub out.

Any ideas on how to test this?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found a solution. You can simply put the following in the fake header:

`#pragma message ("Mock is being included")`

and that will be printed when compiling, so you know which header is being `#include`'d.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to GCC/G++, use the `-M` option.

If you use Visual Studio: Go to Project Settings, then Configuration Properties, then C/C++, then Advanced, then Show Includes. It activates the compiler switch `/showIncludes`.

Both will output the dependency list at compile time.

Better than having to modify header files....